# Xslt transformation for renaming parent and child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on xsl template to append a counter to the tag name. But the below template is not working as expected.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="MAINS">           
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::MAIN)]" />   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MAIN" />   
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'MAINS/MAIN')]">          
    <xsl:copy>        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SUBMAIN" />   
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="//SUBMAINS">           
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::SUBMAIN)]" />   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SUBMAIN" />   
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="MAIN|SUBMAIN">    
    <xsl:element name="{concat(local-name(),position())}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input is as below:

```
    <TEST>
        <TAG1>
           xyz
        </TAG1>
        <MAINS>
            <MAIN>
                <DAT>abc</DAT>
                <SUBMAIN>
                    <DAT2>123</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN>
                <SUBMAIN>
                    <DAT2>456</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN>
            </MAIN>
            <MAIN>
                <DAT>pqr</DAT>
                <SUBMAIN>
                    <DAT2>123</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN>
                <SUBMAIN>
                    <DAT2>789</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN>
            </MAIN>
            <MAIN>
                <DAT>mno</DAT>
            </MAIN>
        </MAINS>
        <SUBMAINS>
            <SUBMAIN>
                <DAT2>789</DAT2>
                <DAT3>sfsfd</DAT3>
            </SUBMAIN>
            <SUBMAIN>
                <DAT2>789</DAT2>
                <DAT3>dsdsd</DAT3>
            </SUBMAIN>
        </SUBMAINS>
    </TEST>
```

Expected output is as below where the tags SUBMAIN or MAIN should be renamed to SUBMAIN or MAIN appended with the index/position:

```
    <TEST>
        <TAG1>
           xyz
        </TAG1>
        <MAINS>
            <MAIN1>
                <DAT>abc</DAT>
                <SUBMAIN1>
                    <DAT2>123</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN1>
                <SUBMAIN2>
                    <DAT2>456</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN2>
            </MAIN1>
            <MAIN2>
                <DAT>pqr</DAT>
                <SUBMAIN1>
                    <DAT2>123</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN1>
                <SUBMAIN2>
                    <DAT2>789</DAT2>
                </SUBMAIN2>
            </MAIN2>
            <MAIN3>
                <DAT>mno</DAT>
            </MAIN3>
        </MAINS>
        <SUBMAINS>
            <SUBMAIN1>
                <DAT2>789</DAT2>
                <DAT3>sfsfd</DAT3>
            </SUBMAIN1>
            <SUBMAIN2>
                <DAT2>789</DAT2>
                <DAT3>dsdsd</DAT3>
            </SUBMAIN2>
        </SUBMAINS>
    </TEST>
```

But the actual output is :

```
<TEST>
<TAG1>
    xyz
</TAG1>

<MAINS>
  <MAIN1>
     <DAT>abc</DAT>
     <SUBMAIN>
           <DAT2>123</DAT2>
        </SUBMAIN>
     <SUBMAIN>
            <DAT2>456</DAT2>
        </SUBMAIN>
  </MAIN1>
  <MAIN2>
     <DAT>pqr</DAT>
     <SUBMAIN>
           <DAT2>123</DAT2>
        </SUBMAIN>
     <SUBMAIN>
            <DAT2>789</DAT2>
        </SUBMAIN>
  </MAIN2>
  <MAIN3>
     <DAT>mno</DAT>
  </MAIN3>
 </MAINS>
  <SUBMAINS>
  <SUBMAIN1>
     <DAT2>789</DAT2>
     <DAT3>sfsfd</DAT3>
  </SUBMAIN1>
  <SUBMAIN2>
     <DAT2>789</DAT2>
     <DAT3>dsdsd</DAT3>
  </SUBMAIN2>
 </SUBMAINS>
</TEST>
```

In the actual result the SUBMAIN Tag under MAIN is not appended with the number.

Comment: **1.** Please show the input too. **2.** Your expected output does not show the numbering you describe.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank u for noticing the errors. I have updated the question with the expected details

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, this returns the expected result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MAIN">
    <xsl:element name="MAIN{position()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::SUBMAIN)]"/>   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SUBMAIN"/>   
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SUBMAIN">
    <xsl:element name="SUBMAIN{position()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>   
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Added:**

Here's another way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MAIN | SUBMAIN">
    <xsl:variable name="n">
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{name()}{$n}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>   
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think also `SUBMAINS` element get its childs reordered. In fact, `MAINS` element, too.

Comment: I tried the transformation online and I didnt get the expected result, the resulting XML is truncated after the SUBMAIN tag transfomation.

Comment: I don't see any of the things you describe: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAY

Comment: Maybe limitation of the tool i used. https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output. Thank you for your inputs. It helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

First, this template never gets matched:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'MAINS/MAIN')]">
```

That's because no NCName can have the `'/'` character.

Second, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- identity template -->

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MAINS">           
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::MAIN)]" />   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MAIN" />   
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="SUBMAINS">           
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::SUBMAIN)]" />   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SUBMAIN" />   
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MAIN|SUBMAIN">
    <xsl:variable name="position">
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{$position}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
   <TAG1>
           xyz
        </TAG1>
   <MAINS>
      <MAIN1>
         <DAT>abc</DAT>
         <SUBMAIN1>
            <DAT2>123</DAT2>
         </SUBMAIN1>
         <SUBMAIN2>
            <DAT2>456</DAT2>
         </SUBMAIN2>
      </MAIN1>
      <MAIN2>
         <DAT>pqr</DAT>
         <SUBMAIN1>
            <DAT2>123</DAT2>
         </SUBMAIN1>
         <SUBMAIN2>
            <DAT2>789</DAT2>
         </SUBMAIN2>
      </MAIN2>
      <MAIN3>
         <DAT>mno</DAT>
      </MAIN3>
   </MAINS>
   <SUBMAINS>
      <SUBMAIN1>
         <DAT2>789</DAT2>
         <DAT3>sfsfd</DAT3>
      </SUBMAIN1>
      <SUBMAIN2>
         <DAT2>789</DAT2>
         <DAT3>dsdsd</DAT3>
      </SUBMAIN2>
   </SUBMAINS>
</TEST>
```

**Note:** two rules for reordering `MAINS` and `SUBMAINS` childs, one rule for enumeration of `MAIN` and `SUBMAIN` elements in the order they were "pushed".

**Addendum:** it's not a good idea to enumerate elements names because almost none SGML/XML vocabulary use this **for siblings** (header in HTML are the exception, but they model hierarchy over a linear text)

**EDIT**: There is a reason because I don't like push style, and that is relaying on the context (current node, current context list, current position). It makes sometimes a code error intractable. For "deterministic" numbering, use `xsl:number`.

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that `SUBMAIN` can be a child of `MAIN` and needs to be numbered in that context too.